# Linux Mint Can't install JDK

Tags: java, linux

I have some stack problems when installing JDK jdk_1.8.005-1_i386.deb on Linux Mint 16 Cinamons petra. I tried with `alien -i jdk-8u5-linux-i586.rpm` and direct install with 
jdk_1.8.005-1_i386.deb I still get this error on my console:

```
(Reading database ... 152427 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking jdk (from .../jdk_1.8.005-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /home/dejjan/Downloads/jdk_1.8.005-1_i386.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/.java/.systemPrefs/.system.lock', which is also in package jre 1.7.055-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/dejjan/Downloads/jdk_1.8.005-1_i386.deb
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically never use the deb file for that matter. From experience it is easier to use the archieve version(tgz).

Download and extract the tgz under /usr/java, then:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/java/jdk1.8-version/ /usr/java/default #so that you can change easily the java version in the future
sudo rm /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/javac /usr/bin/jar
```

Create symbolic links to java executables

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/java/default/bin/java /usr/bin/java
sudo ln -sf /usr/java/default/bin/javac /usr/bin/javac
sudo ln -sf /usr/java/default/bin/jar /usr/bin/jar
```

define a global JAVA_HOME

```
sudo bash -l -c "echo export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default >> /etc/profile"
```

finally let mint know which java to use

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and select the right version from a list

Comment: Thank's for your response.. and that's working exactly.. i try to open sqldeveloper on linux now and work properly

Comment: I would recommend extracting the jdk in /usr/lib/jvm instead of /usr/java because that's where your other jdk (open-jdl, etc.) are already stored.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the error message:

```
 trying to overwrite '/etc/.java/.systemPrefs/.system.lock', which is also in package jre 1.7.055-1
```

Remove your current JDK before installing the new one.

Comment: i was uninstall jre , and install jdk . java jre was uninstalled but i still get the errors